# "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" exception in reading xmlbeans

Tags: java, apache-poi, xmlbeans

I am trying to read XLSX file.its showing this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces()Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
        at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:46)
        at NewClass.main(NewClass.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

error is in line:

```
OPCPackage opc=OPCPackage.open(is);
XSSFWorkbook wb= new XSSFWorkbook(opc);
```

Comment: which of those two lines is line #33?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have correct version (2.x) of **XmlBeans** on you classpath.

Comment: xmlbeans 2.3 is the minimum version to work with Apache POI, anything newer than that ought to work fine too

Answer (score 0):

See [javadoc](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.html) :

XmlOptions setSaveAggresiveNamespaces() : `Deprecated. replaced by setSaveAggressiveNamespaces() in 2.0`. You might be using [Apache XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) 1.x library. Either use latest release(recommended) or change method call to `setSaveAggresiveNamespaces()`

Answer (score 0):

Check that your version of xmlbeans is correct. 
If you are using maven, finds that there is no other unit that contains a different version of xmlbeans. (Use mvn dependency: tree)